# NTLMv1 authentication support for Quarkus

Tags: quarkus, sharepoint-2016, quarkus-rest-client

How does one add or implement NTLMv1 Authentication in Quarkus? I need it so that I can use the quarkus rest client to read and write to Sharepoint folders using their Rest APIs.
See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/sp-add-ins/get-to-know-the-sharepoint-rest-service?tabs=csom

Basically need to be able to authenticate and get the form digest value which expires every x seconds. After which I can include that in the header of the requests.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is an out of the box solution.

If I understand the problem correctly, the easiest way to implement this is probably either using [`@ClientHeaderParam`](https://download.eclipse.org/microprofile/microprofile-rest-client-2.0/apidocs/org/eclipse/microprofile/rest/client/annotation/ClientHeaderParam.html) or [`ClientRequestFilter`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/client/ClientRequestFilter.html), that you register on your client with `@Register(MyFilter.class)`.

Either way, you need to write some code to obtain the token and refresh it when it expires yourself.

Comment: I ended up using the apache httpclient for this, since I did not want to handle all that on my own.